# Understanding linker script values in the context of a simple kernel

Tags: assembly, x86, ld, linker-scripts, multiboot

I'm following this book with regards to developing a little kernel:
https://littleosbook.github.io

I've gotten to the point where the binary has to be linked and I want to be sure that I understand the linker script before proceeding:

```
ENTRY(loader)                /* the name of the entry label */
SECTIONS {
    . = 0x00100000;          /* the code should be loaded at 1 MB */
    .text ALIGN (0x1000) :   /* align at 4 KB */
    {
        *(.text)             /* all text sections from all files */
    }
    .rodata ALIGN (0x1000) : /* align at 4 KB */
    {
        *(.rodata*)          /* all read-only data sections from all files */
    }
    .data ALIGN (0x1000) :   /* align at 4 KB */
    {
        *(.data)             /* all data sections from all files */
    }
    .bss ALIGN (0x1000) :    /* align at 4 KB */
    {
        *(COMMON)            /* all COMMON sections from all files */
        *(.bss)              /* all bss sections from all files */
    }
}
```

First of all, why the specific `ALIGN`ment of the sections (4KB)?
(I think it's very unlikely to be related with optimizations or I could me mistaken and this may be for performance reasons, since otherwise I think there's no restriction on the boot process - confirmed by removing the `ALIGN` function calls in the script)

Then considering the executable to be linked:

```
 global loader                   ; the entry symbol for ELF

    MAGIC_NUMBER equ 0x1BADB002     ; define the magic number constant
    FLAGS        equ 0x0            ; multiboot flags
    CHECKSUM     equ -MAGIC_NUMBER  ; calculate the checksum
                                    ; (magic number + checksum + flags should equal 0)

    section .text:                  ; start of the text (code) section
    align 4                         ; the code must be 4 byte aligned
        dd MAGIC_NUMBER             ; write the magic number to the machine code,
        dd FLAGS                    ; the flags,
        dd CHECKSUM                 ; and the checksum

    loader:                         ; the loader label (defined as entry point in linker script)
        mov eax, 0xCAFEBABE         ; place the number 0xCAFEBABE in the register eax
    .loop:
        jmp .loop                   ; loop forever
```

Am I right when saying that the `.rodata`, and `.bss` sections are not yet needed? (since the kernel still starts fine)

Is there anything else to understand form this little linker script that I cannot get out of the the `ld` manual (which I read a bit to understand the dot, the `SECTIONS` and the entry point)?

It seems that I can re arrange the sections' order in the script and the kernel still works, why is that?

Comment: In some cases I think if you have writable data segment and code in the same 4kb section you can end up with cache invalidations (performance issue). If you start linking with C or another high level language you'll find data placed in `.rodata` (usually _const_ data). `.bss` is for the uninitialized data or data initialized to 0. Usually boot strap code will want to explicitly write zero data to the `.bss` section before code execution that relies on it is executed. In _C_ this is usually done in the C-Runtime code that executes before calling the `main` function.

Comment: If you start out just writing assembler code then many of these optional sections don't apply unless you create them yourself (and it isn't a requirement to have them).

Comment: I won't do it only in assembly, I go to C as much as I can.

Comment: If you are using _C_ then you will almost certainly have to deal with _.bss_ . But that is actually being taken care of if you build an ELF binary and use multiboot. Grub will intiialize your `.bss` to all zeroes for you. Your flags are set to multiboot 0x0 which indicates ELF. What you should do is create a bootstrap stack (when grub loads you you can't rely on there being a valid stack for you to use). You can get an idea of how to do that here: http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones_with_NASM . You'll also want to compile your _C_ code (if using gcc)  with `-ffreestanding -nostdlib -lgcc`

Comment: And lastly if you are going to use C/C++ please heed the advice on the sites about using a cross compiler to generate the kernel. In particular you want an `i686-elf-gcc` cross compiler. The OS development sites should link to instructions on building one. If you use `gcc` that comes in your host environment you may find little gotchyas in the generated code. This is because the compiler and _C_ runtime will target your host environment not a bare bones environment. Trust me you don't want to have to come back to SO to help us figure out bugs caused by using the wrong _gcc_

Comment: @MichaelPetch Could you please recommend a link for building a cross compiler?

Comment: OSDev has instructions on doing it http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler   . What OS are you doing development on? (Ubuntu, Windows, OSX etc?)

Comment: If on Debian install the required dev libraries with the line `apt-get install libgmp3-dev libmpfr-dev libisl-dev libcloog-isl-dev libmpc-dev texinfo` . Use [2.24 of Binutils](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.24.tar.gz) and [GCC 5.2.0](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-5.2.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz) sources. Extract both into a new directory and then follow the instructions per the  http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler_Cross-Compiler link starting at `The Build`. In the instructions don't do any of the lines that start with `mv` (the apt-get ine has already installed them above)

Comment: GCC 5.2.0 is the latest as of this writing. Binutils is slightly older (they are up to 2.25) and I suggest using 2.24. The reason for this is that GCC 5.2.0 will not compile with the current Binutils 2.25 (I learned the hard way).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the handy information!

Comment: No problem. I see I got the link in my last post wrong. It should have been http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler . I got it right in the earlier comment (you probably realized that)

Comment: `section text:` is a bug with the colon on the end, it should be `section text`